# Create my own .net domain name

Tags: debian, bind

I would like create my own domain with bind9 and which would be accessible from the internet.

It is possible ?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can HOST your own DNS zone, but you can't CREATE your own public DNS name.

First, you must register the domain with a registrar because your domain name has to be added to the internet's root DNS servers. You don't have control over the .NET root zone, so that is why you have to purchase the domain and have it registered.

Second, you can then change the authoritative DNS servers for your new domain and point them to your own BIND installation. With the proper configuration, port forwarding / firewall settings, and static IPs you'll be able to host your own DNS zone.

But, there's almost no legitimate reason to do this, because enterprise grade, redundant DNS hosting is included in your domain name registration, which is dirt cheap.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that you need to have at least two authoritative name servers in separate networks.

Comment: Good point. Is this a hard requirement? Or, just something that certain registrars enforce?

Comment: It's part of [IANA Technical requirements for authoritative name servers](https://www.iana.org/help/nameserver-requirements), so it's a global (and a very reasonable) requirement.

Comment: It is not a requirement enforced by registries. Also you may wish to have even more redundancy because even with 2 separate networks, it could be in the same datacenter, hence depending on the same source of electrical power for example... IANA requirements are enforced for TLDs nameservers.

Answer (score -1):

You must purchase the public DNS from a DNS provider. If you didn't register, the client outside won't be able to resolve your IP address since it doesn't have a record on any public DNS server.

You can use bind to build your own domain inside of your production/testing environment, and you must point all your clients to this server as the DNS server.

You can check this illustrate for detailed information about how a DNS works.  https://www.verisign.com/en_US/website-presence/online/how-dns-works/index.xhtml